# Better way of adding values to varying dynamic properties?

Tags: javascript

### Minimalistic way of adding values to dynamic properties?

Lately I find myself in situations where I need to change the inline styles of my divs dynamically.

```
function dynamicCSS(prop, val) {
  el.style[prop] = val;
}
```

If my property is a transform rotate then I would have to format things like this:

```
"rotate(" + val + "deg)"
```

In other cases it would look like this:

```
"scale(" + val + "px)"
```

Or simply for a positional value:

```
50 + "px";
```

So in order to account for all css possibilities **I would have to create an insane amount of if statements. Is there a more elegant way im not away of?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks for it

`rotate(${val}deg`

`scale({val}px)`

`50px`

Comment: Im a bit confused how this is supposed to work. Can you show an example?

Comment: Hello, I learned about template strings but it is not the solution as I still would have to repeat writing different strings for each case